# How to configure Detox on windows platform to run the test for react native apps on android device

Tags: detox, cross-application, mobile-app-testing

Is there any support for this?

I am trying to implement detoxs in windows platfoam to create testing environment for mobile apps. I implemented commands but cannot figure out how to configure it smoothly. Is anyone guide me with this.